# sed - find and replace text containing "/"

Tags: sed

How can I search and replace text that contains `/` with sed?

I currently use the following command which doesn't work

```
sed -i "s/queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-secondary/queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-$newnumber/g" /etc/postfix-$newnumber/main.cf
```

Comment: backslash escape it when not a delimiter or swap delimiters: `s|queue_directory = /var/spool.*|newnumber|`.

Comment: What's the full command for that?

Comment: @WhimsicalWombat - it just feels... cheap. But you're welcome to, and guaranteed at least one upvote if you ping me when through. Teddy - wherever you do `s///` the stuff between those comprise the address and replace fields. If the stuff contains `/` then you just have to use something else like `s|||`, or backslash escape the stuff within like `s/\///`. It works for regular addresses too, but those always require a backslash when not `/` like: `sed '\|^/|s/.//'` which will remove a `/` if it occurs at the head of a line. And so the full command is your command where `s///` is `s|||` instead.

Comment: For more info about regex visit http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html and to try what you want with a little explanation visit http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to pick a different delimiter besides `/`.  For example, using `|`:

```
sed -ie "s|queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-secondary|queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-$newnumber|g" /etc/postfix-$newnumber/main.cf
```

Another approach is to backslash-escape your other slashes:

```
sed -ie "s/queue_directory = \/var\/spool\/postfix-secondary/queue_directory = \/var\/spool\/postfix-$newnumber/g" /etc/postfix-$newnumber/main.cf
```

Two more suggestions for your particular usage.  First, I don't think you need the g flag, unless you anticipate the substitution appearing multiple times in the same line.  Second, if you are just trying to change a directive, you could potentially just change it no matter what the previous value.  For example:

```
sed -ie "s|^queue_directory =.*|queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-$newnumber|" /etc/postfix-$newnumber/main.cf
```